# How to avoid to show the big dot in begin of command output in rhel7?

Tags: linux, redhat, centos7

In rhel7, sometimes systemctl output a big dot in the begin of line. If the appearace of secureCRT was not set to UTF-8, this big dot can not be showed normally. How to avoid to show this character?

```
[root@5520AMS ~]# systemctl status iptables.service

● iptables.service - IPv4 firewall with iptables
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)

   Active: inactive (dead)
[root@5520AMS ~]#
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
LC_CTYPE=C systemctl status
```

`LC_CTYPE=C` switches to a non-UTF-8 locale, which causes systemctl to avoid UTF-8 characters.